# Override color for OxyPlot BarChart not working

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I am using OxyPlot BarChart in my WPF project. I am creating dynamic columns, and changing ColumnSeries.FillColor property with:

```
FillColor = OxyColor.FromRgb((byte)rnd.Next(0, 255), (byte)rnd.Next(0, 255), (byte)rnd.Next(0, 255))
```

For example, our RGB values should be like this: R: 157, G: 21, B: 3
This should give us #9d1503, but instead it is giving #ff9d1503

Because of that my columns not colorful, but all white.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: The `ff` is just full opacity. Your colours are right.

Comment: @PalleDue StrokeColor works, TextColor works, but FillColor doesn't work. I really don't understand why this happening.